# Установка высоты для раскрывающегося списка

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как установить высоту раскрывающегося списка?
Необходимо, чтобы список не выходил за пределы popup окна. Поиск показал пару результатов решения на js, но все они не отличаются качеством кода. Есть ли стандартные методы решения подобной задачи? Или придётся городить свой велосипед?
[image: Раскрывающийся список]

Comment: Попробуйте указать select size подробнее -> http://htmlbook.ru/html/select/size

Answer (score 0):

Все почему-то привыкли, что для верстки раскрывающихся списков в `html` есть только `<select>` и `<option>`. Однако это не так. В `html5` появились новые элементы - `<details>` и `<summary>`. В отличии от обычного `<select>` в `<details>` можно делать раскрывающиеся списки со своей разметкой и легко их стилизовать.

```css
html {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #333;
}

#page-wrapper {
  width: 640px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border-top: 5px solid #69c773;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

h2 {
  margin: 1em 0;
  font-size: 1em;
}

details {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #EEE;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

summary {
  background: #333;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

/* Style the summary when details box is open */
details[open] summary {
  background: #69c773;
  color: #333;
}

/* Custom Markers */
#custom-marker summary {
  font-size: 17px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#custom-marker summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}

#custom-marker summary:before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  content: "";
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4621/treehouse-icon-sprite.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

#custom-marker[open] summary:before {
  background-position: -18px 0;
}


table {
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
}

th {
  width: 200px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

a {
  color: #08C;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <h1>Details and Summary Elements Demo</h1>
  
  <h2>Example #1: Order Information</h2>
  
  <!-- Specifying an 'open' attribute will make all the content visible when the page loads -->
  <details>
<summary>Order #24892105</summary>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Order Date</th>
    <td>30th May 2003</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Order Number</th>
    <td>#24892105</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Courier</th>
    <td>Buy N Large Postal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Shipping Address</th>
    <td>
      P. Sherman,<br>
      42 Wallaby Way,<br>
      Sydney,<br>
      Australia
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Billing Address</th>
    <td>
      P. Sherman,<br>
      42 Wallaby Way,<br>
      Sydney,<br>
      Australia
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
  </details>
</div>
```

Comment: в селекте можно выбрать пункт списка, как это сделать в вашем примере?

Comment: к тому же, в фаерфоксе и ие11 список `<details>` + `<summary>` сразу появляется раскрытым.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko вы решили ко всем моим вопросам писать абсурдные комментарии?

Comment: в данном случае абсурден ваш ответ. `<details>` + `<summary>` не имеют ничего общего с селектом и не предоставляют аналогичной функциональности.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko вы несете бред. select никак нормально кроссбраузерно не стилизовать. Я говорю правильную вещь - сделать верстку наиболее семантикой и валютной. Да, выбор придется делать JS'ом.

Comment: почитайте хотя бы немного о семантике элементов <details> и <summary> прежде чем писать такое :) http://w3c.github.io/html/interactive-elements.html#the-details-element это раз. два — вопрос был не о стилизации селекта, а о количестве выводимых элементов. или вам важно запостить хоть что-нибудь?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko ваши комментарии неконструктивны и вы явно не подкованы в данном вопросе. Не вижу смысла продолжать с вами дискуссию.